# Linq .ForEach Optimization

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

Is there a more elegant and/or faster way of writing the following?

```
foreach(var listing in listings)
{
    listing.Reviews.ForEach(r => r.ListingID = listing.ListingID);
    listing.OpenHours.ForEach(o => o.ListingID = listing.ListingID);
    listing.Photos.ForEach(r => r.ListingID = listing.ListingID);
    listing.Types.ForEach(t => t.ListingID = listing.ListingID);
}
```

All it is doing is going through all the child collections and setting a property on each of the items in the child collections

Comment: Yes, [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx) or  [Parallel Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997425(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Noseratio I am not so sure. It may even be slower, since there isn't any work other than looping and assignment.

Comment: @Noseratio `Right?` not necessarily. Cost of creating tasks and sync mechanisms may result in a slower execution time depending on the size of the lists.

Comment: @Noseratio probably will be slower due to overhead... I'd assume that particular code goes through small number of items (I'd not bother for anything under 1000... and carefully measure above that)

Comment: @Noseratio You should find the guidelines and prove it, if you state something is better.

Comment: @Noseratio I did some tests in the past and it does not seem to handle the list size. Results with Parallel were much slower for small lists.

Comment: @BrunoLM, fair enough.

Comment: I don't think the issue is size of list. But more amount of computation per unit of work. There is a non-zero amount of overhead in bundling the work into a `Task` and then moving it on to another core (think L2 cache etc). Before the work even begins, a thread needs to create the `Task`s and distribute them to each thread. Finally, this operation is most likely memory I/O bound rather than CPU bound.

Comment: This looks like you're assigning the relationship for persistence, in which case, fix your persistence.

Comment: What is the use case for reassigning ids on a collection of listings? I suspect you are having trouble because you are trying to do a fairly complicated set based operation in an object oriented language.

Comment: It's not the SIZE of the List, it's how you use it.

Comment: @Pure.Krome very sexy comment :)

Comment: I am doing bulk inserts(using SQLBulkCopy, and first I have to save  the parents and re-assign the parent ID to children so they save). The performance really is not an issue, I just wanted to write optimized code

Answer (score 1):

If classes hidden under all these properties implement common interface which exposes `ListingID` property, you could do following:

```
foreach(var listing in listings)
{
    // does not create new list or array! just prepares in-memory query
    var items = listing.Reviews
                       .Concat<IEntity>(listing.OpenHours)
                       .Concat<IEntity>(listing.Photos)
                       .Concat<IEntity>(listing.Types);

    foreach(var item in items)
        item.ListingID = listing.ListingID;
}
```

Although, someone may find it a little bit more readable I don't expect it to be faster than your current approach.